# neovim gutter displaying unknown tag ">>"

Tags: neovim

I'm using nvim with some presets that I copied from other's vimrc.

I cannot understand why the gutter (aka SignColumn) on the left side shows ">>" for some lines. Normally the gutter is used by GitGutter for its "+", "-", and "~".

Whenever I'm editing git files, the gutter works correctly, but when I'm editing normal files the ">>" shows up.

What's going on?

Google search didn't find any reference to ">>" in the vim/nvim gutter (aka SignColumn).

Comment: "I'm using nvim with some presets that I copied from other's vimrc." Of course.

Comment: To be perfectly accurate, copied the tools/scripts I wanted from other people's "~/.config/nvim/init.vim".

Comment: Something in "your" setup is defining those signs. Find it and do something about it. See `:help sign-support`.

Answer (score 3):

Stubborn Googling yielded an obscure link to an old thread with a gold nugget inside.

```
:sign list
```

Listed the plug-in that defined the ">>" symbol, **Coc** (Code Completion Engine). More specifically, generated by **CocError**, **CocInfo**, and **CocHint**. Further inspection shows that **cSpell** *"Unknown word"* message was the culprit.

```
:CocDisable
```

Eliminated those annoying ">>" signs. I'd think **Coc** would be smart enough to know that I wasn't writing any code.

Edit: Perusing the **:help sign-support** as suggested by *romainl* also revealed the **:sign list** command.